# Why is the energy of a particle in both a 2D and 3D box proportional to $\frac{1}{L^2}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, schroedinger-equation, dimensional-analysis

The energy of a particle in a 2D and 3D box is given by
$$E= \frac{n^2 \hbar^2 \pi^2}{2 m L^2}$$

where $L$ is the length of the square/cubic box. I would have expected $L^2$ for 2D and $L^3$ for 3D. Why is it $L^2$ for both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a particle in a box of size $L$, $L$ is the only lengthscale, thus the energy has to go like $\frac{\hbar^2}{ mL^{2}}$ by dimensional analysis, in any dimensions. Same thing in 1D too.

Comment: I'm confused over how you've used the term 'length scale'; the Wikipedia page for length scale doesn't make how to interpret this obvious to me. Are you saying that length is necessarily one dimensional? What's the particle physically doing that means $L^2$ is always applicable? Sorry for being obtuse.

Comment: Is it at all because $n^2$ takes into account number of dimensions (as well as energy level), then the rest of the term is basically a scaling factor?

Comment: What I mean is that $L$ is the only length that we have at our disposal in the problem. Thus, the only energy scale we can have is $\frac{\hbar^2}{m L^2}$, so all energies will be in units of  $\frac{\hbar^2}{m L^2}$, independent of the dimension.

Answer (score 2):

The Hamiltonian of a box of non interacting electrons is separable. This means that
$$H = \sum_d H_d$$

and that the ground state wave function (neglecting symmetrization) is given as
$$\psi(r) = \psi_1(r_1) \psi_2(r_2) \ldots \psi_d(r_d)$$.

Then it is easy to show that the energy is

$H \psi = (E_1 + E_2 \ldots E_d)\psi = E\psi$.

So the non-interacting particle in N dimensions has a same Hamiltonian as N non-interacting particles in 1 dimensions.